# Return default value for SelectInput matching current date

Tags: r, date, match, shiny

I'm looking to resolve an issue for displaying a default value in a dropdown (SelectInput) list based on evaluating sys.Date() vs. a data frame with a range of dates.

df1:

```
code   date        group
10001  2015-10-07  a
10005  2015-10-11  b
10022  2015-10-18  c
10032  2015-10-23  d
10044  2015-10-30  a
```

A second df is created to evaluate today's date (which happen's to be 2015-10-18)

```
active.date=as.data.frame((Sys.Date()))
names(active.date)[1]<-"date"
active.date$date=as.Date(active.date$date)
```

I'm sure there may be a slightly cleaner way for that, but it works...

I know this:

```
match(active.date$date,df1$date)
```

will return the correct row for which there is a match, and perhaps is where I need to head to do this...

On the UI side, I have:

```
 selectInput("get.id",label="ID NUMBER", setNames(as.list(df1$code),df1$date)),

 actionButton("submit", "SUBMIT")
```

The first value that shows up in the dropdown list is just the first item from the data frame:

```
2015-10-07
```

What I am looking to achieve is return the default value from the dropdown list to be the active date (for today's example) **when there is a match**:

```
2015-10-18
```

and to return the first item from the list when there is no match. I still want to return all possible values in the dropdown (so that all dates can be selected), and ideally, it would keep the proper sequence of dates appearing in order that they occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would order the data when the app is loaded.  And render the select input accordingly.

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
    shinyUI(
        fluidPage(
            uiOutput('getter'),
            actionButton('submit', 'SUBMIT')
        )
    ),
    shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
        today <- Sys.Date()
        dat <- reactive({
            ind <- match(today, as.Date(df1$date), FALSE)
            if (ind) df1[c(ind, seq_len(nrow(df1))[-ind]), ]
            else df1
        })

        output$getter <- renderUI({
            selectInput('get.id', label="ID NUMBER", choices=as.character(dat()$date))
        })
    })
)
```

Alternatively, you could keep the choices as a reactive and use

```
choices <- reactive({
    ind <- match(today, as.Date(df1$date), FALSE)
    if (ind) df1$date[c(ind, seq_len(nrow(df1))[-ind])]
    else df1$date
})

output$getter <- renderUI({
    selectInput('get.id', label="ID NUMBER", choices=as.character(choices()))
})
```

Comment: this is great thank you! Just so I understand what is happening, when creating ind, what role is "FALSE" playing? And then it looks like we're setting a new df1 where ind appears first (row 6) and then adding the rest of the data frame minus row 6?

Comment: Yea, that's right, `match` has a default value it returns, so the FALSE is telling `match` to return FALSE when there is no match (instead of the default NA)

Comment: It's working great locally (date is Oct 18th), but I suppose shinapps.io server's are located in a different timezone from myself. You wouldn't happen to know how to change to a client's time zone on the? Tried adjusting your code to....today <- Sys.Date() - as.difftime(10, unit="hours"), but it doesn't seem to make a difference once uploaded to the shinyapps servers.

Comment: I'm not sure but have you looked into `session$clientData`?